# How to send ng-repeat index to another ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have an array call "Menu"

```
var Menu = [
        "url" : "#",
        "type" : "F",
        "id" : "F00001",
        "name" : "CUST",
        "child" : [ {
            "type" : "P",
            "id" : "C00001",
            "name" : "CUST INFO"
        }, {
            "type" : "P",
            "id" : "C00002",
            "name" : "CUST BACKGROUND"
        } ]
```

when the TopMenuBar click the "CUST" I expected the select index can put in another ng-repeat like this code below

```
<div id"TopMenuBar">    
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="row in Menu" >
            <a ng-click="row.type == 'P' ? GeneratePage({'txnName':row.name,'txnId':row.id,'txnPath':[row.name],'txnURL':[row.url]}) : angular.noop >{{row.name}}</a></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
 </div>
 <div id="sideMenuContainer">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="row2 in Menu[index].child" >
            <a ng-click="row.type == 'P' ? GeneratePage({'txnName':row2.name,'txnId':row2.id,'txnPath':[row2.name],'txnURL':[row2.url]}) : angular.noop >{{row2.name}}</a></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

THANKS for the answer

Comment: Did you try to save the $index inside the menu array when you click on the "CUST"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access the index of a `ng-repeat` outside the repeat container. For your purpose on the click event, you just pass the object and set the repeat object as the passed object like below.

Add a click event in the `ng-repeat` statement and pass the object to the method.

```
<div id"TopMenuBar">    
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="row in Menu" ng-click="selectMenu(row)">
            <a ng-click="row.type == 'P' ? GeneratePage({'txnName':row.name,'txnId':row.id,'txnPath':[row.name],'txnURL':[row.url]}) : angular.noop >{{row.name}}</a></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

Inside the controller define event as

```
$scope.selectMenu = function(menu) {
    $scope.selectedMenu = munu;
}
```

For the second ng-repeat option define it as

```
<div id="sideMenuContainer">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="row2 in selectedMenu.child" >
            <a ng-click="row.type == 'P' ? GeneratePage({'txnName':row2.name,'txnId':row2.id,'txnPath':[row2.name],'txnURL':[row2.url]}) : angular.noop >{{row2.name}}</a></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The `selectedMenu` in the repeat statement will be the selected menu in the first repeat statement. Hope this will work for you

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
<div class="container1">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="menu in menus track by $index">
            <a ng-click="child($index)">{{menu.name}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="container1">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="menu in menus2 track by $index">
            <a>{{menu.name}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

$scope.child = function(index) {
    $scope.menus2 = $scope.menus[index].child;
}
```